# Ways of determining the position of an element on a page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `offset()` to get the current position of an image just after a UL.  I am positing the image absolutely so that it hangs off the first li as a pointer.  When any li is clicked i want the image to slide to that particular li.

The first time i click on a li it slides to the centre of the page.  But then when i make subsequent clicks it moves the proper distance, only in the centre of the page because its already been set incorrectly.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is my HTML

```
<ul id="llist">
    <li class="t current"><a href="#"><span>solutions</span></a><img src="images/bg-tab-leader-arrow.png" width="24" height="53" title="pointer" class="pointer" /></li>
    <li class="m"><a href="#"><span>credit mangement solutions</span></a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="#"><span>third party additions</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and my JS to date (which also nicely fades out tabs)

```
$('#llist li').click(function() {
    var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
    $('.pointer').animate( {'top': thisTop} );
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
#subheader { position:relative; }
#subheader #llist { float:left; width:286px; margin:0 0 18px 0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
#subheader #llist li { color:#005474; line-height:68px; height:70px; background:url(../images/bg-tab-leader.png) no-repeat; position:relative; }
#subheader .pointer { z-index:1000; position:absolute; top:9px; right:-22px; }
```

Any ideas on why this positions itself in the centre of the page when i first click instead of just sliding it to the relative LI would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused by this line:

```
var thisTop = $('#llist').offset().top;
```

...since it gets the `top` position of the `llist`, not the `<li>` that was clicked.

If I change it to:

```
var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
```

...it seems to work fine.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/hxAzW/1/

---

**EDIT:**

The issue may be that you need to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()`, so that it uses the relative position of the `<li>` *within the container*.

**EDIT:**

Also looks like you need to give `relative` positioning to the container `llist`.

Comment: Ahh sorry i left that in from changing it to test different lines

Comment: Are we talking about the jquery?

Comment: @Andy, I'm guessing you need to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()`. I'll update my answer, but I'm going to have to break a way for a few minutes before I can test.

Comment: I changed it to position instead of offset and its closer :)

Comment: @Andy: Make the `llist` relatively positioned with `position:relative`.

Comment: Cool, now it just needs to position calculated to centre :)  Thanks for all your help on this.

Comment: @Andy: You're welcome. You should just be able to add a few pixels to the result of `position().top` to get it centered. :o) *EDIT: Or add the pixels to the arrow with `margin-top:8px;`, or whatever.*

Comment: Thats what im trying to sort now, thanks, its always a few pixels out one way or another...raaggghh

Comment: I made the image the same size as the list item :)

Comment: @Andy: I was going to mention that, but then I saw that's what you did. Glad it's working. :o)